# Is there a PowerShell variable that can be checked to see if you the script is running in the Azure cloud shell?

Tags: azure-cloud-shell

Something similar to `$IsLinux` or `$IsWindows`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old, but I had the same question and found this environment variable that works for my purposes. I'm not sure if there's another "official" way though.

```
PS> $env:AZUREPS_HOST_ENVIRONMENT
cloud-shell/1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I am not sure how did you run your script. If you use [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job?view=powershell-7) to run the PowerShell script as a background job, you could use [`Get-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-job?view=powershell-7) to see the `State`.

```
Start-Job -FilePath ./GetDate.ps1  
Get-Job
```

[image]

Comment: Why would I do a `start-job` every time I ran a script in the Azure Console? What if I wanted to use the same script locally and in the console but save the data in a different place? I don't want a hack, I want a scalable, portable and testable solution.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest running a command in a try/catch that is specific to cloud shell, if that is what you are looking for?

```
    try {
        $sessioninfo = Get-CloudDrive
        if ($sessioninfo) {
            Write-Host "Running in Cloud Shell mode..." -ForegroundColor Green
            $path = ($home + "/clouddrive/" + "report" + "-$(get-date -Format yyyyddMM_hhmmtt).csv")
        }   
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host "Running in local PowerShell session mode..." -ForegroundColor Yellow
        $path = "C:\localpath\report"+"-$(get-date -Format yyyyddMM_hhmmtt).csv"
    }
```